# Does evolution by selection require that individuals consciously change behaviour in an effort to suit their genes?

Tags: evolution, philosophy-of-science

Imagine an animal that is incapable of digesting a particular kind of food. Now suppose the mutations for digesting that food were to suddenly appear within the population. There still has to be a corresponding change in the animal's behavior, correct?

I mean, I don't go around thinking, "Gee, how could I get the best out of my genes to get ahead of my competition?" There seems to be a need for changing behaviour to get the benefit of the new mutations, which for me allows room for divine providence (e.g. A God) to guide evolution at the level of animal behavior at least.

Am I missing something? Does evolution by selection not require device providence etc?

Comment: The fact that there is not, and there cannot be a scientific proof of God makes any (pseudo)scientific argument referring to God a moot point. If you want to explain something using science then you must stay in the framework of the scientific method. Putting God into the equation is a *deus ex machina* (pun intended) just doesn't work. You can of course explain evolution by means of divine intervention, but you cannot call that science.

Comment: @Nico: I am aware of this. I was primarily interested in the philosophical underpinnings of the naturalistic worldview -- i.e. why certain scientists dismiss God from their personal worldview based on the science. (I initially wanted to post this in philosophy but I wanted a good answer to my question from the biology).

Comment: OK, sorry I did not understand that was the sense of your question. In that case, may I point you to [this excerpt](http://www.users.qwest.net/~jcosta3/article_dragon.htm) from Carl Sagan's beautiful book "The Demon-Hunted World"?

Comment: Going off of your example: I get hypoglycemic if I dont eat well. So if I sat around eating Legos all day I would become ill from lack of nutrients. It would not take long for me to realize I shouldnt be eating Legos. I dont need God to tell me this. The idea of God subconsciously altering someones behavior to "maximize" genes is ridiculous. Why then, does God not prevent two recessive carriers of a disease from mating? What it comes down to is this: Saying "couldnt God do X" is not proof or evidence, so no scientist is going to take it seriously.

Comment: I would also like to point out that as a scientist and a devout atheist, it is not science that convinces me that god does not exist but faith. I can no more prove there is no god than you can prove there is one (or more). Scientifically speaking, the absence of a god is the most reasonable hypothesis given observable data, but that does not make it true. That I _feel_ there is no god is an act of faith no different than yours when you feel there is one. Science can only deal with the demonstrable, faith is beyond its purview.

Comment: @terdon - we'll try to ignore that the basis of science is the faith that the universe is reasonable and orderly :)

Comment: @MattDMo that is not faith, it is an assumption on which our later conclusions are based. Assumptions in logic or science are the equivalents of theorems in math, they are not arguable, they are premises. In any logical edifice, the premises are taken as given and the logic is built on them. You need to accept certain things as premises in order to construct your logic. In a philosophical discussion, I am willing to accept that my perceived reality is likely not real. I cannot accept that premise for a scientific argument or for my day-to-day life though, because that way lies madness.

Comment: Why is it that at least 7 people have voted on answers but only I have voted on the question? Whether we agree with their worldview or not, the OP has asked a perfectly valid question in a non-confrontational manner and deserves an upvote. We should not refrain from upvoting valid questions just because we have a philosophical disagreement with the OP.

Comment: @terdon - I dont think it was a good question. For starters the title is "Why is there such an argument about evolution" but thats not what he is asking at all. Indeed, what he is asking is clear as mud. He first asks about how / if (?) genes can influence behavior. Not a bad biology question, but then he asks about why scientists ignore this, which is a wrong assumption, and not so much a biology question but a philosophical question about scientists. And he ends by asking if he is confused. Four questions if you count the title, none of them related. Im guessing thats why it got 0 upvotes.

Comment: @vonMises I was not suggesting that the question should be upvoted, I was asking people to vote, one way or another. We tend to only vote one answers here and it's a shame. Anyway, the basic question is quite clear, "why do scientists ignore the possibility of a guiding hand in evolution". Yes, it is based on many wrong assumptions but it _is_ clear.

Comment: I edited the title as the previous one was really not helpful. Feel free to roll back if you don't like the edit

Comment: [Understanding Evolution by UC Berkley](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01) is a very short and very introductory course on evolutionary biology that you might want to have a look at.

Comment: @Remi.b — Although the poster may be a troll, your change of title to something that is neither what he intended or, indeed, a title, is unacceptable. I have changed it again (even though it invalidates the argument of my own answer). I would say a better way of dealing with this is to vote to close it as opinion-based. Arguing on the basis of opinions or belief in the divine is clearly unsuited for a scientific forum of this type. I appreciate people not wanting to be accused of avoiding an argument, but do you argue with Jehovah's witnesses and the like that knock on your door?

Answer (score 11):

The theory of evolution via selection does not require any kind of divine intervention. It proposes that [mutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation) randomly occur within the DNA, this causes changes in the phenotype (e.g. allowing digestion of a common food source), these changes can be good or bad (beneficial or deleterious). As a result, those with "good" mutations achieve more reproductions (the fitness of those mutant allele carriers is higher) and those mutations spread through the population. You can not direct the evolution of your DNA because **mutation is random**, even if we artificially induce mutations, **we can not direct what the mutation does to the phenotype** (though we can sometimes induce specific mutations known to have certain phenotypic effects). Selection favours some phenotypes over others but can only work with the mutations it is presented with - it can not direct the evolution of animals with wheels if mutations that allow wheels to form do not occur.

From this sequence you can see the evolution of a phenotype is best explained in a most parsimonious way without the inclusion of divine intervention. It is the principles of [Occam's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor). **Calling divine intervention in to this theory would add further, and unwarranted, complication to the model** and we would then have to find strong evidence for the existence of a divine being, something which is still yet to happen in the eyes of most evolutionary biologists. Strong evidence has been found which suits the theory without divine intervention (including unnecessary and untestable components to a theory goes against the basic principles of science).

Selection itself, though largely involved in evolution, is not necessary for traits to evolve. The [neutral theory](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16120807) proposed by [Motoo Kimura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motoo_Kimura) and developed in the last few decades suggests that traits can evolve with out selection, via genetic drift. This means traits develop in populations purely due to random sampling of neutral (or near neutral) random alleles. The relative importance of Selectionist vs Neutralist theories remains hotly debated within evolutionary biology.

---

**Explaining your imaginary scenario with a current theory of evolution: A new digestive enzyme**

**The scene:** There is a population of 100 deer. 50 males and 50 females. There is a potential for variance in mating success and that mating success is defined solely by the strength of the male.

**Selection affects a trait:** Males that digest their food better grow bigger and stronger. Thus selection favours males that get the most out of their food. If the ability to digest is completely genetically determined by a single locus (for simplification lets say it is) and there is only one allelic variant (one version of the gene) in our first generation then mating success will be equal among the males.

**A mutant arises:** In the next generation a single male carries a mutation in that locus. It is a mutated version of the gene which makes a key digestive enzyme work more efficiently.

**Selection acts:** This male is 10% larger and stronger than other males, and therefore sires more offspring in the next generation than any other male. These next generation offspring (technically half if it was a single mutation in a diploid organism - the other half have the ancestral haplotype) have the mutant allele. Then those males with the mutant allele also get more of the matings and so on and so on.

**The allele is then spreading through the population.** It will continue until all members of the population have the same allele (fixation) or will start over if a new allele arises which is even better. That's all evolution is, no divine beings necessary.

**What if the allele was neutral?** If the gene for a digestive enzyme existed but was not necessary in an organisms diet it would not know it could go out and use that food source. It may not even be able to. For example, a single fruitfly carries a mutation which has no cost and allows it to digest lactose. It is unlikely to be able to utilize that allele, because dairy products are not part of it's diet and not available in the wild. The allele would only drift in the population, eventually being lost (most likely as it starts at low frequency) or becoming fixed in the population. You can see a [genetic drift simulation I wrote in R here](http://griffinevo.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/fisher-wright-genetic-drift-simulation-for-use-in-r/). You can set f=1 and then play around with population size, number of generations, and replicates to get a feel for this process.

Note it is worth considering the effects of pleiotropy (if an allele has a good effect on one trait but a negative effect on another - including traits in different environments) and linkage (if the good allele is close to some deleterious mutations in the DNA it will struggle to spread until it is separated by recombination).

Comment: I think you might improve your answer by telling a bit about what might happen to newly arisen mutation that would be beneficial if the genetic background was different. What is the fate of this mutation allowing to create a new enzyme to digest a food when individuals behave (let's assume the variance in behavior are 100% genetically coded). You might as well give a word about pleiotropy.

Comment: The OP was asking what happen if the beneficial effect of the mutation (new enzyme allowing to digest a new food) is hidden because it is genetically coded that deer (to follow your example) don't eat the food it can now digest. In such a case, the mutation (new enzyme) is not beneficial and does not spread (or only by genetic drift).

Comment: It doesn't mean that you need a god for evolution to occur, it just mean that a mutation that allow better lactose (milk) digestion has a different effect on the reproductive capabilities of a mammal than of an insect. The effect of a mutation depends on the environment and the genetic background in which this mutation appears.

Comment: @Remi.b that's is covered by the neutralist side of things - "..traits develop in populations purely due to random sampling of neutral (or near neutral) random alleles"

Comment: I felt that the OP might wanted a explanation of what might happen to the mutation he was talking about. I wanted to be specific to the OP's example where you provided very good general description. +1 good answer mixing basic process of evolution, philosophy of science and Kimura's neutral theory.

Comment: @Remi.b I get you now, added in a bit.

Comment: @GriffinEvo
>if we artificially induce mutations, we can not direct what the mutation does to the phenotype.

I don't think you meant that. Yes we can direct what the mutation does to the phenotype - we routinely do it in organims we can genetically manipulate (bacteria, yeast, mice etc.) and of course only in cases where we understand the 
relationship between genotype and phenotype.

Better way of putting it would be that in most cases in natural populations we cannot predict consequences of a given mutation, as there are many factors in nature that can influence the fate of that mutation.

Comment: @yotiao by "we routinely do it in organisms we can genetically manipulate" do you mean we can cause a specific mutation to occur?

Comment: @GriffinEvo Yes. We can introduce a specific mutation (substitution, insertion or deletion of a single base pair up to large chunks of DNA) into a specific position in the genome. In many cases, we know a good deal how if affects the phenotype. In other cases, we have no idea but this is exactly the reason it's done.

Comment: @yotiao but this is using an induced mutation to produce an effect on the phenotype, for which the specific mutation has previously been observed to cause the intended phenotype - it's subtly different to what I said. Without *a priori* knowledge of how a mutation affects a phenotype, we can not know what effect a mutation will have on the phenotype,  we must first observe it to understand it's effect (though I'm sure predictive models can or will be built that can simulate the effect of specific mutations).

Comment: @GriffinEvo Yes, you're right for the majority of mutations (some obvious ones excluding, like stop mutations in housekeeping genes). We must have an idea of a genetic basis of a certain phenotype to be able to speculate about effects of potential mutations underlying the phenotype. But the ability of induction of mutation in a defined genomic position allows us to verify/narrow down these speculations in a really clean and clear experimental way.

Comment: [AlleleA1](http://faculty.washington.edu/herronjc/SoftwareFolder/AlleleA1.html) is a great population genetic software that really gives you a good idea how the frequency of alleles is affected by various factors. You don't have to know R to run it, but you need a Mac (a double bonus :-)

Comment: @yotiao the point I am making is that it is not possible to know it without any prior knowledge of the mutation's effect - I can't say "I want to start digesting cellulose better so I'll change my 5,694,237th nucleotide from an A to a C" unless I have tested that beforehand or have explicit information telling me such a change will give that result.

Answer (score 6):

@rg255 already did a good job answering the main thrust of your question, I will address this part: "There seems to be a huge amount of room for divine providence to guide evolution at the level of animal behavior, at least. Why then do scientists with a philosophical materialist outlook gloss over this?"

Of course there is "room", there is room in the theory of evolution to posit that small, green, tasty but mean little pixies come and push the new food down the creature's gullets, thus teaching them to use new food sources. There is room to posit that invisible, intelligent lichen from Alpha Centauri are actually using brain waves to guide the evolutionary choices of species in a global scale.

While there is clearly room to posit these theories, there is absolutely no evidence for them. The scientific community is not "glossing over" anything, it is just ignoring various (infinite in fact) theories for which we have absolutely no evidence in favor of those for which we have. This is a classic fallacy that was very nicely put to sleep by [Russell's teapot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot) argument:

> Many orthodox people speak as though it were the business of sceptics to disprove received dogmas rather than of dogmatists to
>   prove them. This is, of course, a mistake. If I were to suggest that
>   between the Earth and Mars there is a china teapot revolving about the
>   sun in an elliptical orbit, nobody would be able to disprove my
>   assertion provided I were careful to add that the teapot is too small
>   to be revealed even by our most powerful telescopes. But if I were to
>   go on to say that, since my assertion cannot be disproved, it is
>   intolerable presumption on the part of human reason to doubt it, I
>   should rightly be thought to be talking nonsense. If, however, the
>   existence of such a teapot were affirmed in ancient books, taught as
>   the sacred truth every Sunday, and instilled into the minds of
>   children at school, hesitation to believe in its existence would
>   become a mark of eccentricity and entitle the doubter to the
>   attentions of the psychiatrist in an enlightened age or of the
>   Inquisitor in an earlier time.

If you feel that the world you observe is best explained by assuming the existence of an omniscient god who guides the evolutionary process, then that is your right. However, the fact that you believe this to be true does not make it so any more than my believing it to be false disproves it. We are not glossing anything over when we don't take that belief seriously, no more than when we don't take Russell's teapot seriously. The Christian faith, like many others, is built on the assumption that a god exists, it will never attempt to prove or disprove that assumption because such proof would be sacrilege, the entire edifice is built on *faith* not evidence. If we do not share that belief, why should we attempt to fit our observations into the ideological scaffold provided by someone else's belief system?

If you feel that one theory explains what you observe better than another, the onus is on you to prove it so. That is in fact the beauty of science, it is what sets it apart from most other areas of human endeavor: we change our minds when presented with compelling evidence to do so. Indeed, the history of science is littered with discarded theories. If you can come up with any decent evidence to support a theory, then that theory will (eventually) be taken seriously. Until you do, asking others to consider it based solely on the fact that you believe it to be true is hubris to say the least.

Comment: This is a complicated topic. Basically, we differ on what can be known. Knowledge of God more properly falls into "personal knowledge", like knowledge of a particular person. You're quite right to demand a certain level of "proof"(proof, i.e. 100% certainty, only exists in mathematics), and for that I'd recommend Vishal Mangalwadi's "The Book that Made Your World". But to go from mere propositions about God to a personal understanding takes faith.

Comment: @Joebevo exactly, and as such does not fall within the purview of science. That's why nothing is being glossed over, faith is not something that can be approached by the scientific method of observable and repeatable experimentation. Therefore, any theories that base their conclusions on arguments of faith are not relevant to scientific debate. Science only deals with _testable, disprovable theories_ and the existence of a guiding hand in evolution is neither.

Comment: But you can of course argue against the existence of god on the basis that in many religions there are beliefs in acts of god(s) or features of god(s) that are in opposition to scientific knowledge (walking on water, wine from water etc.). By asserting a level of probability on things that people say god does you can indirectly assert the likelihood of god existing in the first place. So because nothing god does / what god is is physically possible as far as science can tell, *very* likely there is no god at all.

Comment: @yotiao well, not really, no. If you start with the premise that god(s) exist, by definition they are above and beyond the laws of physics. Therefore, you expect them to be able to do things that are impossible, otherwise they would not be gods. Deities are not expected to conform to the laws of Nature, they wrote them.

Comment: Heh, this is way OT so we should not go much longer, but I then ask: what is your argument for the premise (god(s) exist) in the first place?

Comment: @yotiao absolutely none, it is not a premise that I hold to be true. However, if you _do_ accept that god(s) exist, then it is to be expected that they don't conform to the laws of physics. If you believe in a creator(s), then you believe that they also created the laws of nature and, therefore, would expect them to be immune to those laws and cannot use these same laws to argue that they don't exist.

Comment: @terdon Yes, in this case this is simply out of realm of science.

Answer (score 1):

I think it pertinent to answer the question posed in the original title, although I will make passing reference to the specific argument the poster makes.

**“Why is there such an argument about evolution?”** This is because evolution is an example of a scientific question which one party approaches from a philosophical standpoint that asserts a particular answer, and so they will never be convinced by scientific arguments that ignore this philosophical position.

Note, that I am not saying that the arguments from those of a particular philosophical standpoint are *necessarily* wrong, only that its exponents will continue to argue (or try to engage people in argument) when the vast majority of scientists have come to regard the question as settled in favour of the counter-view — indeed when that view underpins their daily work.

There are other historical examples of this. Most well known is the Roman Catholic Church's refusal to accept [Galileo’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_affair) espousal of the Copernican view of the Solar System — even to look through his telescope to see the evidence. (I think they have thrown in the towel on that one now.) On the political left you have the promotion of [Lysenkoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysenkoism) by the Soviets.

I would suggest that philosophical attitudes colour contemporary arguments. I suspect many ‘progressives’ would never accept scientific evidence that indicated one ethnic group were less intelligent than another. And it would be naïve to think the stage at which one regards a life as having been formed is independent of any religious or feminist views one may hold. There now. I’ve lost the friends I made in the previous paragraph.

Finally, **your example of an individual acquiring the ability to digest a different food** illustrates my point. You are so convinced that you are right that you have never taken the trouble to find out what the arguments for evolution actually are. It is only under circumstances that an acquired trait provides a competitive advantage that it will be selected for. Think [multi-drug-resistant bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_drug_resistance). You’ll find much more sophisticated arguments on the various ‘scientific creationist’ sites on the Internet, but you would be advised to save your breath, because nobody is listening. As I said, [*la guerre est finie*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_guerre_est_finie_(film)).